# Plotting of Dataframe with two columns having repetitive values

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, dataframe, seaborn

I have a dataframe with repetitive data and I want to plot it (may be using seaborn). column1 has 4 different strings which repeat 6 times each. column2 has their corresponding values in decimals(float). I have to boxplot it with the 4 distinct names on the x-axis and their corresponding values on the y-axis

```
mydata = np.normal(What to write in this!)

sns.boxplot(data=mydata);  

sns.plt.show()
```

Data is of the form:

```
     col_A       col_B     col_C
2    CareNigr     1       593.662
11   JuncEffu     1      1739.839
27   HolcLana    23      3255.829
28   CareNigr     5      2960.367
49   JuncEffu    19      1137.202
66   HolcLana    19      3389.649
67   CareNigr     7      1478.291
68   HolcLana    13      2898.826
84   LychFlos    23      2897.199
87   LychFlos     8      3227.606
90   JuncEffu     1       937.697
98   HolcLana    14      2577.221
108  LychFlos    20      1814.692
127  CareNigr     4      1617.430
139  LychFlos     9       583.174
144  JuncEffu    17      1461.574
148  CareNigr     3      1387.861
156  HolcLana     7      2447.608
167  JuncEffu     1      1566.370
168  HolcLana    20      1759.717
175  JuncEffu    24      1845.036
179  LychFlos     1       598.637
193  LychFlos     1      2673.134
194  CareNigr    19      2037.673
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try `df.boxplot(by='col_A', column="col_C",)`

Comment: Thank you so much @Thomas Tu. I tried it and it compiles without error, but how do I show the plot?

Comment: This will work via matplotlib.  So you might want to use something like iPython, and type in `%matplotlib` and then run this code.

Comment: Perfect! @Thomas. Worked like a charm. Thank you so much.